# I don't understand why I can't read the same values between a Modbus server and a Modbus client using the library pyModbusTCP

Tags: pi-4, server, modbus

I have a problem with a modbus connection with Raspberry pi 4B, let me explain what's going on.
I'm using the pyModbusTCP and I'd like to be able to read the values of coils in a Modbus server on the terminal of a Modbus client on the same machine: raspberry pi 4B.

Currently, the server detects the client's connection to localhost via port 5050, but the values in the variable: coil_values = [False, False, True, True] are not transferred to the client. Despite the fact that the client asks to read the values of these addresses.

Perhaps I've misunderstood or misprogrammed my communication?

I'm providing you the code and some screenshots of the terminal in attachments.

I hope I've made myself clear and someone will be able to tell me where I went wrong or point me in the direction of a possible improvement.

Thank you for your time

SERVER CODE :

```
import argparse
import logging
from pyModbusTCP.server import ModbusServer
import signal
import sys
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time

# Configurer les logs
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Parse args
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', type=str, default='127.0.0.1', help='Host (default: localhost)')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=5050, help='TCP port (default: 5050)')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', help='Set debug mode')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Logging setup
if args.debug:
    logging.getLogger('pyModbusTCP.server').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Variable to store coil values written by the client
coil_values = [False, False, True, True]


# Queue to communicate between threads
coil_values_queue = Queue()

# Function to read coils
def read_coils(address, count):
    return coil_values[address: address + count]

# Function to write coils
def write_coils(address, values):
    global coil_values
    coil_values[address: address + len(values)] = values
    # Put the modified values in the queue
    coil_values_queue.put(coil_values)

# Function to handle signal interruption (e.g., Ctrl+C)
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print("\nStopping Modbus server...")
    server.stop()
    sys.exit(0)

# Register the signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

# Initialize Modbus server
server = ModbusServer(host=args.host, port=args.port, no_block=True)

def start_modbus_server():
    logging.debug("Before starting Modbus server")
    try:
        server.start()
        logging.debug("Modbus server started")
        
        # Main loop for the Modbus server thread
        while True:
            # Read the coil values
            coils_values = read_coils(0, 4)
            # Put the modified values in the queue
            coil_values_queue.put(coils_values)
            # Sleep for a short time (adjust as needed)
            time.sleep(1)
            
    except Exception as start_error:
        logging.error(f"Error starting Modbus server: {start_error}")
        sys.exit(1)

# Start Modbus server in a separate thread
modbus_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_modbus_server, daemon=True)
modbus_thread.start()

try:
    # Main loop for the main thread
    while True:
        # Check if there are modified values in the queue
        if not coil_values_queue.empty():
            coils_values = coil_values_queue.get()
            print(f'Read coils: {coils_values}')
            # Do something with the coil values if needed
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    print("Exiting the main loop.")
    # Ensure the server is stopped when the script exits
    server.stop()
    print("Modbus server stopped.")
```

CLIENT CODE :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

""" Read 10 coils and print result on stdout. """

import time
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient

# init modbus client
c = ModbusClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=5050, auto_open=True, debug=False)

# main read loop
while True:
    # read 10 bits (= coils) at address 0, store result in coils list
    coils_l = c.read_coils(0, 4)

    # if success display registers
    if coils_l:
        print('coil ad #0 to 4: %s' % coils_l)
    else:
        print('unable to read coils')

    # sleep 2s before next polling
    time.sleep(2)
```

[image]

Server terminal :

```
admin@raspberrypi   python3 server_modbus_draft.py --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5050 --debug
2024-01-25 18:39:37,543 DEBUG Before starting Modbus server
2024-01-25 18:39:37,574 DEBUG Modbus server started
Read coils: [False, False, True, True] 
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True] 
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
2024-01-25 18:39:43,504 DEBUG Accept new connection from ClientInfo(address "127.0.0.1, port 49276)
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True] 
Read coils: [False, False, True, True] 
Read coils: [False, False. True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
Read coils: [False, False, True, True]
```

Client Terminal :

```
admin@raspberrypi     python3/read_client.py
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False] 
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
coil ad #0 to 4: [False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: pleade do not post pictures of text ... post text instead ... simply copy the text and paste it into your question ... then everybody can read it, not just the people with good eyesight

Comment: Hello @jsotola, I didn't notice the screenshot wasn't provided with good quality, sorry. I've provided you with the text referring to each terminal below the screenshots if you need it. Thank you for your time!